# How to save logs in a Processing web app using processing.js?

Tags: logging, processing, github-pages, processing.js

I am building a simulation of a microwave web app for my thesis. I found out that with Processing was exactly what I was looking for and with the processing.js it is possible to run it in a web page that I'll use to share the simulation and get user logs.

The main task I have to do is save logs of user actions made on this simulated microwave.
Unluckily, reading the [documentation of processing.js](http://processingjs.org/reference/) I found out the the main features to write on a file are disabled except the [saveStrings()](http://processingjs.org/reference/saveStrings_/) one.
I am using version 1.4.8 the last official release.

Everything is working for me in local, but putting it on web (I am using GitHub Pages) it doesn't write on the file.

I am sure I am using it correctly since locally everything is ok, but maybe something changes in the web. While the program si running i have the logs into a string, so any other method might be ok too.

Any suggestions or tips about how to fix it or about any different way of how to collect those logs are accepted.

I really appreciate your help,
thank you.

Comment: Edit: i find out this update of processing.js called p5.js, but the problem about saving the logs is still there: createWriter and its functions make a file and download it for the user, meanwhile I need to save those logs locally.

Answer (score 1):

P5.js is not an update of Processing.js in the slightest: Processing.js was a Processing 2.5 API-compatible Javascript library that would load Processing code, convert it to JS, and run it in the browser (and was discontinued in December 2018, and should no longer be used for any new projects) whereas P5.js is a *separate* project that reimagines Processing "if it had been invented for the web" with a completely different API.

Both run in the browser, but they're very different.

Now, because they run in the browser, what they'd *can't* do is read and write files from your file system. That would be incredibly insecure, so browsers won't let you. So you either get to aggregate your logs and then trigger a "save as...", or you can send your data to some logging server, using plain JavaScript (because remember: you're in the browser, and both Processing.js ad P5.js are javascript libraries. Anything JavaScript can do, you can call inside your for-the-web Processing script)